# Set inputType for an EditText Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

How do we set the input type for an EditText programatically? I'm trying:

```
mEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

According to the [TextView docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), the programmatic version of android:password is [setTransformationMethod()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTransformationMethod(android.text.method.TransformationMethod)), not setInputType().  So something like:

```
mEdit.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Just to add to this, you need to call setTransformationMethod *instead* of setInputType. Calling setInputType after setTransformationMethod causes the EditText to not be in password mode again.

Comment: this answer is wrong for the question being asked. This only transforms the text entered in the `EditText` (replaces characters with password dots). This has no effect whatsoever on what is allowed to be entered in the `EditText` itself.

Comment: setInputType ultimately calls setTransformationMethod from within, so if you pass the TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD to setInputType it will do this for you. The problem seems to ley in calling setSingleLine after calling setInputType which will call setTransformationMethod with null or the single line transformer thus clearing out the password transformer.

Comment: after call  setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance())i can't able to edit it

Comment: but the password will show up in suggested text next time the field is used

Answer (score 447):

For setting the input type for an EditText programmatically, you have to specify that input class type is text.

```
editPass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Your tip worked perfectly for me! I had a similar problem with programmatically setting the input type to multiline.

Comment: What is the significance of having a bitwise OR operator here? Sorry, I'm new to android.

Comment: I disagree  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD doesn't work for me but setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()); does !

Answer (score 86):

Here are the various Input Types as shown on the standard keyboard.

[image: input types demo]

### Setting the input type programmatically

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

Other options besides `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType).

### Setting the input type in XML

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
/>
```

Other options besides `text` can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType).

### Supplemental code

Here is the code for the image above.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    List<InputTypeItem> inputTypes;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        initArray();
    }

    public void onChangeInputTypeButtonClick(View view) {
        if (counter >= inputTypes.size()) {
            startOver();
            return;
        }
        textView.setText(inputTypes.get(counter).name);
        editText.setInputType(inputTypes.get(counter).value);
        editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
        counter++;
    }

    private void startOver() {
        counter = 0;
        textView.setText("");
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }


    private void initArray() {
        inputTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("date",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME | InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("datetime", InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME | InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_NORMAL));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("none", InputType.TYPE_NULL));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("number",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("numberDecimal",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("numberPassword",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("numberSigned", InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("phone",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("text",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textAutoComplete", InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textAutoCorrect",  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textCapCharacters",  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textCapSentences",  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textCapWords",  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textEmailAddress",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textEmailSubject", InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textFilter",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textLongMessage",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_LONG_MESSAGE));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textMultiLine",  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textNoSuggestions", InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textPassword",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textPersonName", InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textPhonetic",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PHONETIC));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textPostalAddress", InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textShortMessage", InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_SHORT_MESSAGE));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textUri",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textVisiblePassword",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textWebEditText",  InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textWebEmailAddress", InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EMAIL_ADDRESS));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("textWebPassword", InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD));
        inputTypes.add(new InputTypeItem("time", InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME | InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_TIME));
    }

    class InputTypeItem {
        private String name;
        private int value;
        InputTypeItem(String name, int value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

### See also

- [Getting the current `InputType`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49664186/3681880)

Comment: Thanks for `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL` for decimal numbers!

Comment: what is the type for first row as number and rest text?

Answer (score 36):

i've solve all with

```
.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

for see clear data and

```
.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

for see the dots (if the data is a number, it isn't choice che other class)

Comment: This worked, thanks! One question tho, why do I need to add 'or' when changing from plain text to password type? Why can't I simply do this: .setInputType( InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);? I tried and it didn't work.

Answer (score 20):

To only allow numbers:

```
password1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

To transform (hide) the password:

```
password1.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 10):

For Kotlin:

```
    val password = EditText(this)
    password.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
    password.hint = "Password"
```

Answer (score 9):

```
editText.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

//you can change TYPE_...  according to your requirement.

Answer (score 6):

This may be of help to others like me who wanted to toggle between password and free-text mode. I tried using the input methods suggested but it only worked in one direction. I could go from password to text but then I could not revert. For those trying to handle a toggle (eg a show Password check box) use

```
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(check.isChecked())
            {
                edit.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                Log.i(TAG, "Show password");
            }
            else
            {
                edit.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                Log.i(TAG, "Hide password");
            }
        }
```

I have to credit [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/518641/Show-hide-password-in-a-edit-text-view-password-ty) for the solution. Wish I had found that a few hours ago!

Answer (score 6):

To unhide password:

```
editText.setInputType(
      InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|
      InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
);
```

To hide password again:

```
editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

also you have to be careful that cursor moves to the starting point of the editText
after this function is called, so make sure that you move cursor to the end point again.

Answer (score 1):

Hide:

```
edtPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
edtPassword.setTransformationMethod(null);
```

Show:

```
edtPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);                    
edtPassword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: This works for me but after setting it back to password mode, the spacing between the dots is reduced.

Comment: If I use `edtPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);` then the spacing is correct. Kudos for the `edt` prefix on the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

InputType will not work, Easiest way is to setTransfromationMethod()

- To show the Password

  ```
   edittextPassword.setTransformationMethod(null);
  ```
- To hide the Password Again

  ```
   edittextPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the EditText/TextView tag in your layout

```
android:password="true"
```

Edit: I just re-read your post, perhaps you need to do this after construction. I don't see why your snippet wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't have a layout file in this case, the fields are being generated programatically.

Comment: Yeah it is being done after construction, not sure why it's not working either!

Comment: this option now deprecated!!

Comment: this thing is only one which works for old android 2.3, I've upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know the expected Answer is in `Java` . But here's my 2 cents of advice always try to handle view related stuff in `XML` (atleast basic stuff) so I would suggest rather use a `xml` attribute rather than handling this use case in `java`

```
    <EditText
     android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```

Comment: In some cases you may want to toggle between different input types e.g. hiding/showing of password entered in a field; which is what let me to this page

Comment: but for that there is an option in EditText that let's you show/hide password no need to do it on your own also it gives a nice animation for that.

Comment: thanks for the info, I have seen it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163578/3310235

Answer (score 0):

```
field.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not the direct answer to the question. For most of the cases, either of the above answers should be right. However, none of them helped in my case.

I have a custom ViewGroup in my project that contains a text for the Title and an EditText. This EditText receives Texts, Numbers, Password, Phone, etc. depends on the case and place is being used. The Caller of the view group supposed to tell what is the input type.

**Important**: Setting the inputType should be the last set of the EditText (or at least it has to come after setting the Text of the EditText), otherwise, there is no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is based on multiple answers and in **Kotlin**

1- In my XML file the passwordEditText is initially set to hide the text

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:inputType="textPassword" /> // this line hides the text- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48950491/4833705

<Button
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton" />
```

2- In the Activity, I press the toggleButton to  change the passwordEditText's visibility via togglePasswordEditTextVisibity():

```
binding.toggleButton.setOnClickListener {
    togglePasswordEditTextVisibility()
}

fun togglePasswordEditTextVisibility() {

    val hiddenPassword = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
    val visiblePassword = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD

    if (binding.passwordEditText.inputType == hiddenPassword) {

        binding.passwordEditText.inputType = visiblePassword
        binding.passwordEditText.transformationMethod = HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance() // https://stackoverflow.com/a/48602018/4833705
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password is now Visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    } else {

        binding.passwordEditText.inputType = hiddenPassword
        binding.passwordEditText.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password is now Hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    binding.passwordEditText.setSelection(binding.passwordEditText.text.length) // puts the cursor at the end of the text in the EditText because when you change the input type the cursor will be automatically set to the starting point- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9893496/4833705
}
```