# EditText, inputType values (XML)

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, android-inputtype

Where can I find the values that `InputType` can has?

I'm aware of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html, but how should the values look like in layout XML files?

Comment: A bit late in the day, but I think this might be what you're looking for:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html

Comment: This may be what you're lookng for:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_inputType

Comment: Specifically http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#inputType

Answer (score 321, accepted):

You can use the properties tab in eclipse to set various values.

here are all the possible values

- none
- text
- textCapCharacters
- textCapWords
- textCapSentences
- textAutoCorrect
- textAutoComplete
- textMultiLine
- textImeMultiLine
- textNoSuggestions
- textUri
- textEmailAddress
- textEmailSubject
- textShortMessage
- textLongMessage
- textPersonName
- textPostalAddress
- textPassword
- textVisiblePassword
- textWebEditText
- textFilter
- textPhonetic
- textWebEmailAddress
- textWebPassword
- number
- numberSigned
- numberDecimal
- numberPassword
- phone
- datetime
- date
- time

Check here for explanations: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Comment: Description...?

Answer (score 36):

## Supplemental answer

Here is how the standard keyboard behaves for each of these input types.

[image]

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49622027/3681880) for more details.

Comment: Perfect example with vidoe about how your keyboard looklike after using input type

Answer (score 0):

```
android:inputMethod
```

is deprecated, instead use `inputType` :

```
 android:inputType="numberPassword"
```