# Enable email keyboard on android for input type email

Tags: android, html, email, input, android-webview

I am creating application with `WebView`. I use the `WebView` to show HTML pages, containing input fields. If the HTML input fields expect an email address to be typed by the user, then I want to enable an email-friendly keyboard layout. Is it possible to set up the HTML or the `WebView` to show an email-friendly keyboard on Android, like you can on iPhone?

Comment: This could be using any browser for eg android, opera mobile, chrome or firefox.

Comment: Solution: HTML5 input tag has some limitations to enable the keyboard, refer the following link to check the supported keyboard types with input tag.

http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html

Answer (score 29):

You will only put

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

in your edittext box.

Comment: Thanks Vijay, the question is for a webpage. If your solution will work for web, can you please put some more details? I don't think we are using layout.xml at all for this?

Comment: As mentioned, this does not answer the question which is about web pages.

Answer (score 5):

yes it is posible

in your Edittext xml just add the attribute

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

see this for more

[EditText, inputType values (xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712761/edittext-inputtype-values-xml)

Comment: Where is edittext (xml) located? Like I sad we are not using any xml I guess.

Answer (score 2):

just add this for your EditText or TextInputEditTex or whatever editable field.

```kotlin
 this.inputType = (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS )
```

**Note:**
if when you try to specify the input type and doesn't work put inside one "onFocusListener", i had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 input type `email`, which on recent Android versions brings up a qwerty keyboard with additional `@` and `.` keys.

```
<input type="email" name="myinput" />
```

This doesn't seem to work on Gingerbread.