# textView wont display decimals

Tags: java, android, int, decimal

I am having an issue with my program, my textveiw will not display any decimals, heres the break down on whats happeneing.  The user enters a number in a textEdit (Also how do i make the textedit only accept numbers AND a decimal point?) that number gets converted to a int, sent to my second activity, diveded by 3600, then displayed in a textveiw box.  The issue is that when that number is displayed it has no decimal value, for example if its less than 1 it will not display anything, how can i go about fixing this? i need it to at least go to the 1000th place.
Here is my code one activity1:

```
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayTracker.class);
    // Gather text from text boxes
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hourly_wage);
    //Create String from text
    String message1 = editText.getText().toString();
    //Convert String to Int
    int HW = 0;
    try{
        HW = Integer.valueOf(message1);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        //do something else here
        //for e.g. initializing default values to your int variables
    }
    // Send Integers to PayTracker.java
    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_HW, HW);
    // start new activity
    startActivity(intent);
```

And then this is activity2 where the number needs to be displayed:

```
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Receive messages from options page
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int HW = intent.getIntExtra(Options.MESSAGE_HW, 0);
    // Calculate pay per second
    int PPS = 0;
    PPS = (HW/3600);

    // set textView
    TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.yourpay);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(PPS));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Declare as **float PPS = 0F;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use doubles or floats. From what I see, everything should work except that you forgot that 5 divided by 2 as int is 2, and not 2.5.

so do as gtumca said and use doubles; longs are just bigger ints.

in other words...
activity1

```
try{
    HW = Double.valueOf(message1);
}
```

activity 2

```
//double HW = intent.getIntExtra(Options.MESSAGE_HW, 0);
double HW = intent.getDoubleExtra(Options.MESSAGE_HW, 0);
     // pay is rarely a round number
double PPS = HW / 3600;
```

Comment: i just tried this and i think it broke the division and display somehow, no matter what number is entered it always displays 0.0

Comment: whoops, sorry, that's probably because one shouldn't use getIntExtra to get double extras...

Comment: Got it! changed it to getDoubleExtra and everything works!! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `int` as data type  so you are getting `int` values only

```
double PPS = 0;
^^^^^^
instead of           
int PPS = 0;
```

Comment: That only lets it go to the 10th place, i need at least the 1000th

Comment: You mean you want to be as precise as 0.001 right? Use float or long, those should have enough precision.

Comment: @user804967 say i want to use long, on my first activity instead of converting the string to an int how do i convert it to a long?

Comment: It's impossible since decimal part is permanently dropped. After conversion you'll get XXX.000000000

Comment: @chester1000 the string wont hold the decimal until its converted to the long?

Comment: integers are whole numbers. longs are just bigger whole numbers.
floats and doubles are 'fractions' and can hold a value between any two whole numbers.

the string can mediate for any one of those when it comes to message passing.

Answer (score 1):

> that number gets converted to a int

Integers dont have decimals :)

As to the EditText only accepting numbers:

[EditText, inputType values (xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712761/edittext-inputtype-values-xml)
Set one of those types to your EditText in the Layout xml like:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Comment: ohh alright, what should i use instead of an integer that has that much precision?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use float or double to keep numbers with such big precision. Float and double cannot represent decimal fractions exactly due to their internal representations. Please, check [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if you want 1000-digit precission(or more).