# Android:inputType; what are the differences?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-edittext

I'm currently working on a create account activity for an Android app and I'm selecting the types of input for each editText box. Problem, there seems to be so many possibilities with no differences between each.

The only noticeable one is email which puts the "@" symbol on the keyboard.
Do you know what are the differences between each or where I can find them? The Android doc doesn't help much..

Thanks!

Comment: They all do a variety of different things.  For instance email give the user an @ on their soft input.  number only gives the user the option to enter in a number, textPassword makes the text not visible for security, etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EditText, inputType values (XML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712761/edittext-inputtype-values-xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is the complete doc about this:**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

A lot of explanation for each of them.

**Examples**

> ***A password field with the password visible to the user***: inputType
>   = TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
>
> ***A multi-line postal address with automatic capitalization***: inputType =
>   TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS |
>   TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE
>
> A time field: inputType = TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME |
>   TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_TIME

---

**Or for your purpose:**

> int   TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS -> Variation of TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
>   **entering an e-mail address**.
>
> int   TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT   Variation of TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
>   **entering the subject line of an e-mail**.