# Change from number keypad to general keypad

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

In Some phones when number keypad is displayed unable to go back to normal keypad because in my scenario numbers are the primary for me so need number keypad to be displayed at first go later if we want to switch to normal keypad it's not working.
Mostly I observed this issue in Lenovo phones/tablets.

Edit: Basically iam using Digitkeylistener for some seperators to get added programatically if i make use of Textkeylistener its throwing n number crashes randomnly.So I want to use Digitkeylistener but with normal keypad.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712761/edittext-inputtype-values-xml

Answer (score 0):

Change *inputtype* attribute of your Edittext in XML, to *text*

Answer (score 0):

You can add below line in your code

For Numeric,

```
editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
```

For Qwerty,

```
editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY);
```

This is only to set input type but you can change keyboard and will not restrict Edittext to enter number only.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but actually Iam using custom edittext which is making use of Appcompact edittext , where iam using these functions  setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(19)});
            setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890" + mSeparator)); which making only number keypad to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can add below line in your XML for getting **general keyboard**:

**android:inputType="text"**

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You can add below line in your XML for getting **Number keyboard**:

**android:inputType="number"**