# Accept number and letter input from SIP when android:inputType of EditText View set to "numberDecimal"

Tags: android, input, keyboard, android-edittext, sip

When a View loaded, I want to force SIP to open and show Keyboard with numbers. Also, I want a editText view accepts Letter and Number input from SIP

```
XML
            <EditText android:id="@+id/search_bus_by_num_keyword"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:lines="1" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            />

Code
    editTextSearchKeyword = (EditText) context.findViewById(R.id.search_bus_by_num_keyword);
    editTextSearchKeyword.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // Perform action on key press
                context.hideSIP(editTextSearchKeyword);
                searchRoute();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    editTextSearchKeyword.setText(searchKeyword);

    editTextSearchKeyword.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.showSoftInput(editTextSearchKeyword, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

When the View loaded:
http://pwong.name/sip_01.png

When I change the SIP from Number to Letter:
http://pwong.name/sip_02.png , I cannot enter Letter to the editText view.

Is it possible to enter both of number and letter for a editText if I set android:inputType="numberDecimal" to it? Is it possible to change android:inputType at run time?

Comment: Second picture link is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext) question about how to change the InputType in code. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) link for the EditText input types. As far as your requirements of "I want to force SIP to open and show Keyboard with numbers. Also, I want a editText view accepts Letter and Number input from SIP" - I do not understand. I do not think you can have multiple modes of input for an EditText.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```