# Show the password with EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I use an EditText to enter password.
And a CheckBox to show password or not.
Below function is the part:

```
public void ShowPassword() {
    if (cb.isChecked()) {
        password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
    } else {
        password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

When it checked, it show password.
But when it not checked, it does show stars.
How to modify it to show star while the cb is not checked?

Comment: You forgot to ask the **question**.

Comment: Look at my answer about what is 129..

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I don't know exactly the specifics, but this code should work:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(!isChecked) {
                    password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                } else {
                    password.setInputType(129);
                }
            }
        });
```

`129` is the input type set when setting `android:inputType="textPassword"`

edit:

as mentioned in @user370305's answer, `129` is the value of the bitwise or operation when you do

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: no idea either. probably a combination of the InputType ints, but I don't know which one. I came up with 129 by logging the InputType before changing anything.

Comment: 1) this should hide back password when isChecked = true. Looks like opposite;
2) hides it the password back?

Comment: instead of 129 you can use (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)  
because
int TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD = 128;
int TYPE_CLASS_TEXT = 1;

Comment: @GeorgeTheodorakis You need to remove the String "VISIBLE_" from your comment to make it correct.

Answer (score 49):

This is not an answer,

Answer already given and accepted..

I just want to clarify about  `129`

```
password.setInputType(129);
```

is Actually,

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

**'|' is not a pipe**, it's a `bitwise OR`. It takes two binary numbers and if either of the bits of equal value are 1,

How this relates to the input type: Each of the InputTypes are actually just ints. 
`TYPE_CLASS_TEXT is 1`, and `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD is 128 (or 10000000)`.

Perform a `bitwise OR` on them:

```
00000001

10000000

------------

10000001 which is 129.
```

Try entering `input.setInputType(129);` instead, you'll see it'll work. :)

Comment: Thanks, that cleared my mind. It's just sad knowing that the sdk doesn't have a single constant for something you can actually set on the xml itself.

Answer (score 16):

I think you are using the wrong function. I make that way and work perfectly:

```
passwordEditView = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.password);
final CheckBox showPasswordCheckBox = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
showPasswordCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (showPasswordCheckBox.isChecked()){
            passwordEditView.setTransformationMethod(null);
        }else{
            passwordEditView.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: haven't encountered PasswordTransformationMethod before. interesting. what else can it do?

Comment: Where you put null, another post says to use this: *HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance()* - from:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/19109453/2162226 . Your answer worked for me, but do you know if one is better than another? .. thanks

Comment: Thank you!  This is the right answer.  The accepted answer does not work in my tests.  Please see this post about why setInputType is not the right one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank You

Answer (score 10):

This might help you mate

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // checkbox status is changed from uncheck to checked.
        if (!isChecked) {
            // show password
            editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        } else {
            // hide password
            editText.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Found this answer to be really helpful and looks like the proper way to achiever this. But wondering why does this have least downvote :(

Answer (score 3):

The Password Visibility Toggle feature has been added to support library version 24.2.0 enabling you to toggle the password straight from the password field without the need for a CheckBox.

You can make that work basically by setting an inputType of password on the `TextInputEditText`. Here's how to do that:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I discovered this myself when suddenly the toggle started appearing on my screens. Is there any way to turn this off?

Comment: Nevermind, I just saw your article on Medium where you explain the options

Comment: Link to the document?

Comment: Here it is: https://medium.com/@moyinoluwa/password-visibility-toggle-android-support-library-revision-24-2-0-98b422087e5a#.z7cjlzmni

Answer (score 3):

use app:passwordToggleEnabled = true; available from Android support library version 24.2.0.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_medium">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/btn_sign_in"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of visible password, can you try with TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL

```
public void ShowPassword() {
password.setInputType((cb.isChecked()) ? 
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL : InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there are the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Call this method inside your `OnCheckedChangedListener`

```
 public static void toggleShowPassword(boolean show, EditText editText) {
    if (show)
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
    else
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    editText.setSelection(editText.length());
}
```

The `EditText` cursor resets its position after changing the `InputType` that's why we add the last line `editText.setSelection(editText.length())`

Answer (score 1):

This will work -

```
public void ShowPassword() {
    if (cb.isChecked()) {
        password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    } else {
        password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on the off chance that you are using Xamarin (Visual Studio Mac as it's now called) you can achieve it this way (I used a Switch)

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Toggles the password.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="field">Field.</param>
 /// <param name="isChecked">If set to <c>true</c> is checked.</param>
 private void TogglePassword(TextView field, bool isChecked)
 {
      /// masks with password character
      if (isChecked)
      {
           field.TransformationMethod = new PasswordTransformationMethod();
      }
      /// unmasks password
      else
      {
           field.TransformationMethod = null;
      }
```

Then on your Switch .click do something like this

```
switch.Click += delegate {
            TogglePassword(textView, switch.Checked);
        };
```

Answer (score -1):

okay:

To show readeable text:

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
```

To "star" the password:

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
```

But why? The `Type_Text_Variation_Password` set it to stars, but why does only adding `Type_Claas_Text` revive the visibel password?
I would have thought that `Type_Text_Variation_VISIBLE_Password` comes into play ...

Comment: TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD also lets the keyboard know that it should treat the user input as a password and hence not store it as an autocomplete suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void onCheckBox(View v2)
{



    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.pass_Check);
    EditText et1=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edt_Pass);
        if(cb.isChecked())
        {
        et1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
        }
        else 
        {
        et1.setInputType(129);
        }

}
```