# Programmatically change input type of the EditText from PASSWORD to NORMAL & vice versa

Tags: android, passwords, android-edittext

In my application, I have an `EditText` whose default input type is set to `android:inputType="textPassword"` by default. It has a `CheckBox` to its right, which is when checked, changes the input type of that EditText to NORMAL PLAIN TEXT. Code for that is

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

My problem is, when that CheckBox is unchecked it should again set the input type to PASSWORD. I've done it using-

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

But, the text inside that edittext is still visible. And for surprise, when I change the orientation, it automatically sets the input type to PASSWORD and the text inside is bulleted (shown like a password).

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: How to set email type for edit text mailEdt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EMAIL_ADDRESS); not seems to work.

Comment: Use `mailEdt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);`. Works for me.

Answer (score 416, accepted):

Add an extra attribute to that `EditText` programmatically and you are done:

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

For numeric password (pin):

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Also, make sure that the cursor is at the end of the text in the `EditText` because when you change the input type the cursor will be automatically set to the starting point. So I suggest using the following code:

```
et_password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
et_password.setSelection(et_password.getText().length());
```

When using Data Binding, you can make use of the following code:

```
<data>
        <import type="android.text.InputType"/>
.
.
.
<EditText
android:inputType='@{someViewModel.isMasked ? 
(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD) :
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT }'
```

If using Kotlin:

```
password.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
```

Comment: as noted for correct answer - instead of changing selection you can use `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`

Comment: i don't understand why in the world android chooses to move the cursor, it just makes developers life much more difficult.

Comment: _+1_ for here is [best answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext)

Comment: How to write | in layout file when using data binding.I tried this:  android:inputType='@{oneField.IsMasked==true ? (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | inputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD) : InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT }' It doesn't compile

Comment: @Vlado It works for me using Data Binding as well. I have updated my answer.

Comment: If the user is editing the middle of the password field, this will constantly put the cursor at the end. I'd recommend using `editText.getSelectionStart()` and `editText.getSelectionEnd()` with `setSelection(start, end)` to avoid this issue.

Comment: People shouldn't even be looking further down. This is the best answer and would suggest that you make @JM Lord's suggested change.

Answer (score 72):

use this code to change password to text and vice versa

```
mCbShowPwd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // checkbox status is changed from uncheck to checked.
                if (!isChecked) {
                        // hide password
                    mEtPwd.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                } else {
                        // show password
                    mEtPwd.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                }
            }
        });
```

for full sample code refer http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/518641/Show-hide-password-in-a-edit-text-view-password-ty

Comment: HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance() showed password, and PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance() hide password ... implementation is correct but the comments are reversed

Comment: This is the best answer, to complete it, just move the cursor to the last character with: txtpassword.setSelection(txtpassword.getText().length());

Comment: For a moment it seems not working due to point highlighted by EL-conte De-monte TereBentikh. Josh suggestion is also helpful. This is best answer.

Comment: Simple and best thnks

Comment: You are THE professor my friend! With this solution you are not facing issues with font after changing back to Password mode (secure text).

Comment: This answer better than accepted answer `setInputType` which cause hint added extra spacing between characters.

Comment: But still, you should define `android:inputType="textPassword"` as default in xml or else even `android:maxLines="1"` will not works to make it single line.

Comment: This way is better than `setInputType`, because it preserves the keyboard layout (see the [pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58442682/192373))

Answer (score 18):

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | inputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Method above didn't really work for me. Answer below works for 2.2 sdk.

> password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());

[Set inputType for an EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext)

Answer (score 16):

Another simple example using **ImageView** to toggle visibility with less code, because of single **InputType** assign we need only equality operator:

```
EditText inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
ImageView inputPasswordShow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePasswordShow);
inputPasswordShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         if(inputPassword.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD) {
              inputPassword.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
         }else {
              inputPassword.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD );
         }
         inputPassword.setSelection(inputPassword.getText().length());
    }
});
```

Replacing :

```
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
```

With :

```
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
```

Will give the same result but shorter word.

Answer (score 13):

```
Checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // checkbox status is checked.
                if (isChecked) {
                        //password is visible
 PasswordField.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());     
                } else {
                        //password gets hided
             passwordField.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());       
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

For kotlin users:

```
password.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
```

Comment: And this will only hide password symbols?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
mytext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: Please read the question first. I want to toggle between password field and textfield. This will give me numeric textfield.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code to change password to text and vice versa.
This code perfectly worked for me.
Try this..

```
EditText paswrd=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.paswrd);

CheckBox showpass=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.showpass);
showpass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
        paswrd.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    }else{
        paswrd.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    }

}
});
```

Comment: How is it different from the accepted answer? Please read the question and the answer carefully before spamming.

Answer (score 5):

### Ok So after hours of trying finally implemented it. Below is the code ..

```
  buttons.get(2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       if(buttons.get(2).getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.show))){
           editTexts.get(1).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
           editTexts.get(1).setSelection(editTexts.get(1).getText().length());
           buttons.get(2).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hide));
        }else{
           editTexts.get(1).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
           //editTexts.get(1).setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
           editTexts.get(1).setSelection(editTexts.get(1).getText().length());
           buttons.get(2).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.show));
       }

    }
});
```

---

Explanations:- I have a button with default text as show. 
  After onclick event on it checking if button's text is show.
If it is show then changing the input type,adjusting the cursor position and setting new text as hide in it.

When it is hide... doing reverse i.e. hiding the password,adjusting the cursor and setting the text as show. And that's it. It is working like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

This is the full onClick handler for the Image/Button to show/hide the password.

```
    new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // current ursor position
            int cursorPosition = edtPassword.getSelectionStart();

            // toggles the control variable
            isPassworsVisible = !isPassworsVisible;

            // sets the image toggler inside edit text
            passwordVisible.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(isPassworsVisible ? R.drawable.ic_eye_checked : R.drawable.ic_eye_unchecked));

            // apply input type
            edtPassword.setInputType(isPassworsVisible ? InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD : InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

            // returns cursor to position
            edtPassword.setSelection(cursorPosition);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for `edtPassword.getSelectionStart()`.

Answer (score 3):

The Password Visibility Toggle feature has been added to support library version 24.2.0 enabling you to toggle the password straight from the `EditText` without the need for a `CheckBox`.

You can make that work basically by first updating your support library version to 24.2.0 and then setting an `inputType` of password on the `TextInputEditText`. Here's how to do that:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

You can get more information about the new feature on the developer documentation for [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html).

Answer (score 3):

Since the Support Library v24.2.0. you can achivie this very easy

What you need to do is just:

1. Add the design library to your dependecies

   ```
   dependencies {
        compile "com.android.support:design:25.1.0"
   }
   ```
2. Use `TextInputEditText` in conjunction with `TextInputLayout`

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
       android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
           android:id="@+id/etPassword"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:hint="@string/password_hint"
           android:inputType="textPassword"/>
   </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
   ```

`passwordToggleEnabled` attribute will make the password toggle appear

3. In your root layout don't forget to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
4. You can customize your password toggle by using:

`app:passwordToggleDrawable` - Drawable to use as the password input visibility toggle icon.
`app:passwordToggleTint` - Icon to use for the password input visibility toggle.
`app:passwordToggleTintMode` - Blending mode used to apply the background tint.

More details in [TextInputLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html).
[image]

Answer (score 3):

After you `setInputType` for a password field, you will have [problem with **FONT**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52176331/5381331)
Here is my solution for show/hide password without font problem

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    findViewById(R.id.button_show_hide_password).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isPasswordVisible(edtPassword)) {
                enableInputHiddenPassword(edtPassword);
            } else {
                enableInputVisiblePassword(edtPassword);
            }
            edtPassword.setSelection(edtPassword.getText().length());
        }
    });
}

final int INPUT_TYPE_VISIBLE_PASSWORD = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD;
final int INPUT_TYPE_HIDDEN_PASSWORD = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD;

private boolean isPasswordVisible(EditText editText) {
    return editText.getInputType() == INPUT_TYPE_VISIBLE_PASSWORD;
}

private void enableInputVisiblePassword(EditText editText) {
    Typeface cache = editText.getTypeface();
    editText.setInputType(INPUT_TYPE_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
    editText.setTypeface(cache);
}

private void enableInputHiddenPassword(EditText editText) {
    Typeface cache = editText.getTypeface();
    editText.setInputType(INPUT_TYPE_HIDDEN_PASSWORD);
    editText.setTypeface(cache);
}
```

Note: I use `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` instead of `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` or `HideReturnsTransformationMethod` because I want the keyboard display both text and number

[DEMO](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidPasswordFont)

Answer (score 3):

Use Transformation method:

To Hide:

```
editText.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
```

To Visible:

```
editText.transformationMethod = SingleLineTransformationMethod.getInstance()
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove `android:inputType="textPassword"` from your layout. That is why it is switching back to password when the orientation changes. Because each time the orientation changes the view is being recreated.

As for the first problem try this:

```
String text = password.getText();
password.setText("");
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
password.setText(text);
```

basically emptying out the text before you change the input type and then add it back.

Comment: Not working. I even tried putting `password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);` immediately after initialization, but alas!

Answer (score 2):

some dynamic situation `holder.edit_pin.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);` will not work so better use both like that

```
holder.edit_pin.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
holder.edit_pin.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Note : this is suitable for when you are using dynamic controls like using arrayaapter

Answer (score 2):

My search for a similar solution for Visual Studio / Xamarin lead me to this thread.  Below is what worked for me with Xamarin.  Note that this implementation retains the `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS` flag when switching between modes.

`EditText et = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.ET);`

To show characters:
`et.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword | Android.Text.InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions;`

To hide characters:
`et.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationPassword | Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText;`

To set position to end:
`int position = et.Text.Length;`
`et.SetSelection(position, position);`

Comment: how to use this code `if (edittext.getInputType() == (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD )){

                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD );
            }else{
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD );
            }` for Visual Studio/Xamarin..?

Comment: i mean how to get the inputtype of the edittext in if() condition..?

Answer (score 2):

I change the input type on my checkbox, so on my `OnCheckedChangeListener` i do:

```
passwordEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT| (isChecked? InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD|~InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD : InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD));
```

And it finally worked.

Seems like a boolean problem with `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`. Invert the flag and it should fix the problem.

In your case:

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD|~InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional comment on the correct answer provided by @Rajkiran, you may want to add

```
etPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

to the NORMAL input state so that the users wont be annoyed by the keyboard's auto-suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Complete code when you want to apply the Password visibility in Password edit text.

Create a handle [ Any drawable or Checkbox]

on click or on Checked/Uncheck write this:

```
 if (edittext.getInputType() == (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD )){

                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD );
            }else{
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD );
            }
```

Do not forget to write this line:

```
 edittext.setSelection(edittext.getText().length());
```

It resets the cursor to the end of line.

Comment: @PKR check the implementation buddy, which in this case is ready to use! :)

Comment: @sud007 do u have any idea that how to write the if condition in Xamarin/visual Studio..?

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

final int[] count = {0};

```
    showandhide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(count[0] ==0)
            {
                password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                count[0]++;
            }
            else {

                password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                showandhide.setText("Hide");
                count[0]--;
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers of [neeraj t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19109453/2914140) and [Everton Fernandes Rosario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28091065/2914140) I wrote in Kotlin, where `password` is an id of an EditText in your layout.

```
// Show passwords' symbols.
private fun showPassword() {
    password.run {
        val cursorPosition = selectionStart
        transformationMethod = HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance()
        setSelection(cursorPosition)
    }
}

// Show asterisks.
private fun hidePassword() {
    password.run {
        val cursorPosition = selectionStart
        transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
        setSelection(cursorPosition)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

etPost.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_SHORT_MESSAGE);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To change your password to visible text, use this

```
profileSignupDialogBinding.signupDialogPassword.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
```

To change it back to hidden text, use this

```
profileSignupDialogBinding.signupDialogPassword.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
profileSignupDialogBinding.signupDialogPassword.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
```

This should work well.