# Android - Change on screen keyboard shift state

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have two EditTexts in an activity for activating my app. The first stores a name and has an input type set to textCapWords, the second stores the activation key and has an input type set to textCapCharacters.

The problem is that when you select the first EditText after being in the previous, capslock is still on and is on even if you move onto another activity. What I'd like to do, without having to create my own Input method, is to move it down to shifted, or even fully switch off capslock. I've tried using an instrumentation object to send a shift key and even a capslock key, but that must only affect hardware keyboards. I would think this should be easy to do.

Here is an excerpt of the layout file, It works fine on 2.3.7 and lower. It just seems on 4.0.4 the input isn't changing.

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_device_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:hint="Please type in a unique name."
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
   />

  <EditText
       android:id="@+id/et_activation_key"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
       android:maxLength="48"
 />
```

EDIT:Only other thing I have is two textchanged listeners that both set their respective edit text's error to null. if the count is 1. So they're not affecting functionality.

EDIT:Oh, also when if the first edit text if you manually switch capslock off it uses normal input type rules(lower case if there is a letter before and shifting on space for a new word).

EDIT:

```
et_DeviceName.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher()
                                          {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count )
                                            {
                                                if(count == 1)
                                                {
                                                    et_DeviceName.setError( null );
                                                }
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after )
                                            {                                                           
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void afterTextChanged( Editable s )
                                            {
                                            }
                                          }
                                    );

et_ActivationKey.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher()
                                             {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count )
                                                {
                                                    if( count == 1 )
                                                    {
                                                        et_ActivationKey.setError( null );
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after )
                                                {
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void afterTextChanged( Editable s )
                                                {
                                                }
                                             }
                                           );
```

EDIT: I've given up working with the soft keyboard and have solved my problem by manually capitalising the EditText as text is entered. Here is my code below for anyone who encounters the same problem.

```
    et_DeviceName = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.et_device_name ); 
    et_DeviceName.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS );
    et_DeviceName.setText( MainActivity.DEVICE_NAME );              

    //Move the cursor to the end of the text, for easy editing
    Selection.setSelection( et_DeviceName.getEditableText(), et_DeviceName.getText().length() );

    et_ActivationKey = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.et_activation_key );       
    //et_ActivationKey.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS );

    btn_Activate = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btn_submit_act_key );

    et_DeviceName.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher()
                                              {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count )
                                                    {
                                                        if(count == 1)
                                                        {
                                                            et_DeviceName.setError( null );
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after )
                                                    {
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void afterTextChanged( Editable s )
                                                    {                                                           
                                                    }
                                              }
                                        );

    et_ActivationKey.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher()
                                                 {                  
                                                        boolean capitalise = true;

                                                        /* Exists because for some reason the text randomly goes lower case, when this happens the methods are called 3 times.
                                                         * So this tracks how many times the methods have been called and if called amount is already on two then it will re-capitalise.
                                                         */                                                         
                                                        byte calledAmount = 0;

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count )
                                                        {
                                                            if( count == 1 )
                                                            {
                                                                et_ActivationKey.setError( null );
                                                            }

                                                            if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && count != before)
                                                            {
                                                                capitalise = true;
                                                            }
                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after )
                                                        {
                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void afterTextChanged( Editable s )
                                                        {
                                                             if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB )
                                                             {
                                                                 calledAmount ++;

                                                                 if( capitalise || calledAmount == 2 )
                                                                 {
                                                                     capitalise = false;
                                                                     calledAmount = 0;

                                                                     s.replace( 0, s.length(), s.toString().toUpperCase() );
                                                                 }
                                                             }
                                                        }
                                                 }
                                           );
```

NOTE: I made an assumption when checking against HoneyComb, the version were the problem is may be lower or higher (higher most likely).

Comment: Give us an example of another activity and how do you set it up. _*Note: When you set the input method to `textCap*` it will always set the caps lock on._

Comment: please show us some code which causes the problem that will be more helpful for us

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :

```
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS;
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS;
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES;
```

example : [example of inputType](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/text/method/BaseKeyListener.java.shtml) or information : [information about inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES)

Edit: here is a discussion about this in stackoverflow 
[Programmatically change input type of the EditText from PASSWORD to NORMAL & vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892617/programmatically-change-input-type-of-the-edittext-from-password-to-normal-vic)

**EDIT:**

```
EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.yourLayout.et1);
et1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS); // capitalize all characters

EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.yourLayout.et2);
et2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES); // capitalize the first
                                                          // letter of each sentence
```

**EDIT2:**

```
EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.yourLayout.et1);
et1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);

EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.yourLayout.et2);
et2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

Comment: Nope, did not work. Has Google changed the API so capslock stays on?

Comment: If not this seems like a bug.

Comment: did you remove from the xml the inputType lines? 
because those example show how to change it programmaticaly

Comment: yep, I tried the KeyListener, but that stopped me from entering in any text.

Comment: The Keylistener I spoke of is the one you posted "example of inputType" I used it by setting one of my edittexts' keyListeners. My one as I said just sets their error to null if their count is above 1.

Comment: also check my edited answer, I don't think you need a key listener just to change the input type.. just set it onCreate() when you invoke the EditTexts

Comment: I realise that, the code above is exactly what I have. As mentioned my problem is that changing from the EditText that has capital characters inputType to any EditText that doesn't be it in the activity or not doesn't disable capslock and allow the input to follow the rules, unless the user disables capslock. I'm starting to think this is a bug  as in 2.3.7 and earlier inputType doesn't modify the shift on the soft keyboard. I reckon they haven't properly implemented the new functionality. But anything else you can think of is appriciated.

Comment: try to check my new edited answer.. 
and see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

Comment: I've tried that already and it still doesn't work, thanks for your offerings but I've kludged it to work. Which I'll post above.