# How to set the cursor to the right (EditText)?

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

How to set the cursor to the right with right align and hint text?
Is it possible?

I have a AutoCompleteTextView and a EditText with Text right align and an hint text.
Now if one of them is focused the curser is before the hint and not at the end of the line.
So it looks like now it's bad...

I've also tried to set the cursor position, but it didn't help of course.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/input_snm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:hint="@string/input_snm"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/Button_berechnen"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_medium" />
```

*Image: EditText*

[image: Image: EditText]

Ok, I think it's an System error, isn't it?

Comment: can you see my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
if (your_edittext.getText().length() > 0 ) {
    your_edittext.setSelection(your_edittext.getText().length());
}
```

Can you add this line to your `EditText` xml

```
android:gravity="right"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"//you set this as you need
```

But when any Text writing you should set the paddingleft to zero

you should use this on `addTextChangedListener`

Comment: Did you use if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo. Gettext() >0) then Set cursor

Comment: I even tried it on 4.0.3 - there it works but not on 4.1.2 (S3 Stock & PA)

Comment: I mean when the Set selection method did you use the if Control and what is the error when you use setselection

Comment: I edit my answer, if it gives  error please show error

Comment: So if it is Empty the cursor is beginning so what is the problem

Comment: see at the picture, that's an empty edittext - the cursor is at the start of the hint in 4.1.2 (not in 4.0.3...) - and for me, it looks strange... - it should be like 4.0.3 at the end (if gravity is right)

Comment: yes, and in the autocompletetextview its the same (subnetmask)

Comment: is there - I just post one of them

Comment: this is only if the text is longer then the view, isn't it?

Comment: Did you try android:ellipsize="end"?

Comment: I dont understand you can Set your own paddingleft as you need and when Ã Text Enter you can Set paddingleft to 0 programmtically

Comment: Is it Works? Can you check

Comment: no change; I mean padding is for the whole edittext -> the start from the left and not for the cursor;
I've a relative layout...

Comment: So there is one way I think,  instead of hint you settext  as email and give text Color it looks as hint and the cursor is in the end,  and when Ã Text Enter you should delete Text firstly and Change text Color,  this solve your problem

Comment: Sorry,  what you mean when you say Keyboard

Comment: if I set it to keyboard I coild also type letters - without  them I could only write what I need (numbers, dots and slash)

Comment: You can Change it programmatically like this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892617/programmatically-change-input-type-of-the-edittext-from-password-to-normal-vic** or you should use keylistener to abort chars which you dont want but I Select first one

Answer (score 1):

Set the `android:Theme.Light` style on the activity (theme) and  `android:gravity="right"`.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me.

textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);