# Change EditText value from text to password and vice versa on ToggleButton checked

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I am studying programming in Android and I'm hitting an issue. I have this toggle button and when I input a text and the button is on, the text is starred (passworded, call it whatever you want) and when the button is off, the text is a text. However, I am hitting an issue and I don't see the problem.
The block of code looks like:

```
toggleCommand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(toggleCommand.isChecked()){
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                } else{
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                }
            }
        });
```

I don't see the problem. Can you tell me what did I do wrong and explain?
When I turn on the application.. I type something in and it's passworded. I press the button to uncheck it and the passworded text turns into a text. I press the button again and instead of getting passworded again, the text stays normal.

Comment: May this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
toggleCommand.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            if (toggleCommand.isChecked())
            {
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            }
            else
            {
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
        }
    });
```

More info: http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=27

[Programmatically change input type of the EditText from PASSWORD to NORMAL & vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892617/programmatically-change-input-type-of-the-edittext-from-password-to-normal-vic)

edit: Further explanation on setInputType here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

Comment: This worked, but I don't get the logic behind the code. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
toggleCommand = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_your_togglebutton) ;
toggleCommand.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton, boolean isChecked) 
    {
        if(isChecked)
        {
            input.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        } 
        else
        {
            input.setTransformationMethod(null);
        }
    }
});
```

You can read more about it on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html#ClickListener).

---

**UPDATE**

To make this kind of manipulation, you can use [TransformationMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TransformationMethod.html).

So, to set the text to a hidden password, you must use [PasswordTransformationMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.html), and to turn it to text again, you just set the `TransformationMethod` to `null`, this way, no transformation will be applied to the text.

Hope this helps you.