# How to change attributes of controls with MainActivity.java file

Tags: java, android

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Your Name"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:text="Click Me" />
```

Now, on the click of a button, I want to change the `editText` attribute to `android:inputType="text"`

How can we do this with Java code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically change input type of the EditText from PASSWORD to NORMAL & vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892617/programmatically-change-input-type-of-the-edittext-from-password-to-normal-vic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

now click of button change the edittext input type like this

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```