# Can an EditText change Soft Keyboard based on the current character length

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

App users are required to enter a postcode. The postcode format is always in the following format: 1-9, 1-9, A-Z, A-Z Eg. "45GB"

At present I have a working solution with 4 `EditTexts` each set to its specific inputType. I have a Text Watcher which moves the focus to the next empty `EditText` once users have entered an input.

Is there a solution which can be achieved where I can use 1 `EditText` and change the keyboard input based on which character the user is entering in the order.

Short Version: Can I change between a number keyboard input / qwerty input automatically within a single `EditText`.

Comment: Use this alongwith textwatcher https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892617/programmatically-change-input-type-of-the-edittext-from-password-to-normal-vic

Comment: Thanks @VivekMishra this has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set maxLength

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:inputType="textFilter"
android:maxLength="8"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: android:inputType="number"

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but this doesn't answer the question above. I have both Number & Text input seperately on 4 EditText. I want the same usability for the users, using only 1 EditText

Comment: When you use inputType="number" it disables " " and "-" chars. You can keep using this type and specify that the " " char should be counted as a digit by specifying digits="0123456789 " in the layout xml as well.

Comment: the requirement is to have a different input type after every character typed.

Comment: use edittext.setonTextchangelistner..