# how to force number keyboard when inputtype is set to numberPassword on Android

Tags: android

I was wondering how to configure an EditText element to show a number keyboard like the one shown when I specify its inputType as `numberPassword`.

When masked, I have it set to

```
maskEditText.setInputType(
                InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

which shows this keyboard
[image]

whereas when unmasked/showing, I have the input type set to

```
maskEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

which shows this keyboard:
[image]

I'd like to find a way to keep the keyboard consistent, preferably the keyboard with only numbers but at this point, I'd settle for anything consistent.

Comment: android:inputType="number"

Comment: sorry. I should have clarified that I would like to preserve the masking behavior that I get from inputType `numberPassword`. I'll update the OP

Comment: `android:inputType="numberPassword"` forces input type only numbers and masks. If there's anything else, can you explain it?

Comment: I'd like to toggle between masking and unmasking without the keyboard changing types.  I'm indifferent to which keyboard I keep as long as it's the same between toggling

Comment: This [has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19109453/192373) circa 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `android:inputType="number"`? The complete reference of available input types can be found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Comment: sorry. I should have clarified that I would like to preserve the masking behavior that I get from inputType `numberPassword`. I'll update the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can either add `android:inputType="Number"` in edittext or set programatically as well:

```
final EditText input;
input.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: sorry. I should have clarified that I would like to preserve the masking behavior that I get from inputType `numberPassword`. I'll update the OP

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same input type, but change the transformation method:

```
pw.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
      pw.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    }
    else {
      pw.setTransformationMethod(SingleLineTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    }
  }
```

Note that the same works for field of type `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`, but the keyboard will like

[image]

Comment: This answer is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19109453/192373).