# Set visibility of password in edittext

Tags: android

This code is correct when the inputType is text but i want the same for password type number.On click of the checkbox i want the password to be visible.

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                } else {
                    password.setInputType(129);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: try this android:inputType="textPassword"

Comment: setInputType() did not work for me when I wanted to reset the field to hidden text - but *passwordEditView.setTransformationMethod(..)* did - from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19123514/2162226

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                } else {
                    password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried like this :getEditText().setInputType(
    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | (((CheckBox) view).isChecked() ? 
    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD:
    InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL)); But it did not worked.

Comment: @user1744952 Change it to: getEditText().setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | (((CheckBox) view).isChecked() ? InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD: InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL));

Comment: @user1744952 I think you are using | (OR) in your setinputType, that's why it may be taking 1st option as the input type of your edittext

Answer (score 1):

The Password Visibility Toggle feature has been added to support library version 24.2.0 enabling you to toggle the password straight from the EditText without the need for a CheckBox.

You can make that work basically by first updating your support library version to 24.2.0 and then setting an inputType of `numberPassword` on the TextInputEditText. This works for input types `textPassword`, `numberPassword` and `textWebPassword`.

Here's how to do that:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

You can get more information about the new feature on the developer documentation for [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

For numbers use:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
                password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            } else {
                password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: No it did not work I tried like this: getEditText().setInputType(
    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | (((CheckBox) view).isChecked() ? 
    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD: But it did not worked.
    InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED));