# How exactly passing two integers to a method that accepts one integer works in JAVA ? ( Android )

Tags: java, android, methods, parameters, method-parameters

Please see Amitku 's answer on: [Set inputType for an EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext)

Can anyone explain me how passing an (int | int) works for a method that accepts an (int) ?

Thank you.

Edit after answers:

But when you pass only one of the parameters, the method does not work as expected?
So what exactly is going in there if we are passing only one of the integers?

Comment: The `|` character is used as a bitwise `OR`. The example in that answer isn't passing two `int` parameters, it is `ORing` the two and passing the result as a singlr `int`.

Comment: But when you pass only one of the parameters, the method does not work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` is the "bitwise inclusive OR" operator, read more about it in [the Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

You can see a few tables on how [bitwise operators work here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)

Answer (score 0):

Only one int is being passed.  | is an infix operator that returns the bitwise-or of its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually only one `int` as the `int | int` is a bitwise OR resulting in a single `int`.