# Set edittext input to password in fragment. (programatically)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I got problem with setting `EditText` to password input type.

I try all stuff from stackoverflow, but nothing works when my `EditText` is in Fragment.

```
passBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
passBox.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Try both of this and together in any combinations.

```
public void setViews(Context activity)
{
    ...
    passBox = new EditText(activity);

    passBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    passBox.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
}
```

In activity:

```
cFragment confFrag = new cFragment();
confFrag.setViews(this);
...
confFrag.passBox.setText(settings.getString(PASS, DEFAULT_PASS));
```

ANSWER:

```
passBox.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Must be called after adding `EditText` to other Views.

```
passBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Remove hints, so it is usefull too. Anywhere before transformationMethod.

Comment: Cn you post you fragment code.Just check tht you are pasing correct context to it.

Comment: Its a lot of code, I'll edit and post you function that create views

Comment: Ok sure.just do post problem area atleast.Because at my end both the syntax are working fine.Just may be its related to fragment context issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the `setViews` after the `onCreateView` method from the fragment is done and for the EditText it is enough to use:    `text.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());` .

Comment: That is good answer, just found that, but cant answer own question. + for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
passBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674741/how-to-set-input-type-as-password-to-edittext-programatically