# EditText attributes programmatically - text won't wrap

Tags: android

I have the following **EditText** working as expected.

```
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etMensagem"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_message"
                android:minLines="4"
                android:text="@string/send"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"/>
```

But the attributes need to be set programmatically (all but layout_width and height).

Here is my try:

```
    edit_text.setText(context.getString(R.string.enviar_mensagem));
    edit_text.setMinLines(4);
    edit_text.setHint(context.getString(R.string.hint_message));
    edit_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

But when I do this, the text does not wrap. Even though it's a multiline EditText, it keeps text on a single line, unlike the XML version.

What am I missing?

Comment: have u used this android:scrollHorizontally="false"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800511/770467

> For setting the input type for an EditText programatically you have to
>   specify that input class type is text

Final solution:

```
etMensagem.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u have to do this

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:singleLine="false"
```

Comment: I didn't work. Besides, I need to set them programmatically (question updated), thanks anyways.