# how can i set android inputType as textPassword

Tags: android, android-layout, passwords, android-edittext

I have a dialog box that i have created. this is the code for edittext box. but i want the text to be like password textbox. what change can i do?

```
android:inputType="textPassword"   


final EditText input = new EditText(Setting.this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                  input.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: are you setting title

Answer (score 1):

May be this

```
EditText dt = new EditText(this);
dt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

[Set inputType for an EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext)

Comment: No. this is not working. the text is appearing as text itself

Answer (score 0):

```
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | inputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```