# Programmatically setting up password dots in EditText

Tags: android

I've been attempting to programmatically set up my edittext as a password field as follows:

Method 1:

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Method 2:

```
password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Method 3:

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Method 4:

```
    public class MyPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
};

// Call the above class using this:
text.setTransformationMethod(new MyPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

I created my edittext as follows:

```
        // Create the password edittext
    EditText etPwrd = new EditText(this);

    // Customise the password edittext
    etPwrd.setLayoutParams(etPwrdParams);
    etPwrd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.etlogin);
    etPwrd.setTextSize(18f);
    etPwrd.setLongClickable(false);
    etPwrd.setPadding (5,0,0,0);
    etPwrd.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    etPwrd.setTransformationMethod(new MyPasswordTransformationMethod());
    etPwrd.setTypeface(officialRegularFont);
    //etPwrd.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    //etPwrd.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    etPwrd.setSingleLine();
    etPwrd.setHint(R.string.password_text);
    etPwrd.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

    });
```

I have been unsuccessful using all of the above approaches as the edittext still displays the characters when a user types into them.

I'm aware in XML how to set up an edittext to be a password field but I need to this programmatically.

Comment: Method 4 should work.might be you would have missed adding inputtype for EditText in XML file.

Comment: add this line ' etPwrd.setTransformationMethod(new MyPasswordTransformationMethod());' after 'etPwrd.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback' and it should work

Comment: Welcome,Always Dont forgot to add setTransformationMethod() at end of all declaration of edittext

Comment: Yes indeed .. at the very end .. cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to create another password transformation method, you could do that.

```
password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Note: This shows the character while typing and makes it dot after few milliseconds.

Comment: _+1_ for here is [best answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext)

Answer (score 4):

In onCreate() add these two lines while creating EditText

```
    et2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
    et2.setTransformationMethod(new MyPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

then create `MyPasswordTransformationMethod` class in same activity like this

```
public class MyPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: HI krishna, the programmatic bit doesn't work. As for the XML since I'm developing everything progrmmatically i can't call an edittext from an XML file

Comment: then while creating EditText add this line password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

Comment: If you still have problem post the code were you was creating edittext programatically

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I've included the programmatic creation of my edittext which involves your suggetion with regards to settransformationmethod();

Comment: android:password="true"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"