# Android Get EditText Input Type At Runtime

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I have a custom implementation of an edit text class.

Based on these XML attribute.....

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

I want to be able to know this at run time (In Java Code)

I have found this method which gives me the input type

```
getInputType()
```

And these are the values returned based on the XML I posted above.

> 97,97,33,129

However, these do not correspond to the constant values listed here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

How can I know the input type of an edit text at run time?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType

Comment: @AlexChengalan ah thats perfect. thanks. Post it as an answer and i would be happy to accept :)

Comment: SO not only about accepts and points. Happy to hear it helped :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers you are getting are decimal numbers.For example **textPassword** has constant value `0x00000081` in hex.When you convert that in decimal it will give `129`.

Hence the output you are getting is perfect.

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AinputType) to find the list of all input-types with their hex values.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to get the InputType from an EditText

To get the input type use [`getInputType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getInputType()).

```
int inputTypeValue = editText.getInputType();
```

The `InputType` values are defined (in hexadecimal) in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType).

You can test the values with something like

```
if (inputTypeValue == InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) { ... }
```

#### See also

- [Setting the `InputType`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49622027/3681880)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link. You see that the exact number you get is by 'OR'ing the two Constants:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android%3AinputType

like to get the value of `textEmailAddress`, [OR] `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` with `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS`,

like this: `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS`.

Please see the code:

```
String strInputType;
            final int inputType = editText.getInputType();
            switch (inputType) {
                case (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT): {
                    strInputType = "Name ";
                }
                break;
                case (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT): {
                    strInputType = "Password or Confirm Password ";
                }
                break;
                case (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT): {
                    strInputType = "Email ";
                }
                break;
                case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE: {
                    strInputType = "Phone Number ";
                }
                break;
                case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME: {
                    strInputType = "Date ";
                }
                break;
                case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER: {
                    strInputType = "Number ";
                }
                break;
                case InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS: {
                    strInputType = "Address ";
                }
                break;
                default: {
                    strInputType = "Field ";
                }
                break;
            }
            Resources res = baseActivity.getResources();
            String message = res.getString(R.string.field_blank, strInputType);
```

Happy Coding!