# Edit text Password Toggle Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, gesturelistener

I am trying to show user the typed password in edit text whose input type is text Password.

I implemented gesturelistener over the toggle icon like this-

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.ivPasswordToggle:

                switch ( motionEvent.getAction() ) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"show",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        etPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        etPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"hide",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

i dont know what is wrong, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: my toasts are working fine , but no effect on text of edit text

Answer (score 66, accepted):

(updated for AndroidX)

Since the Support Library v24.2.0. you can achivie this very easy

What you need to do is just:

1. Add the design library to your dependecies

   ```
    dependencies {
        implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1"
    }
   ```
2. Use `TextInputEditText` in conjunction with `TextInputLayout`

   ```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
   ```

`passwordToggleEnabled` attribute will make the password toggle appear

3. In your root layout don't forget to add  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
4. You can customize your password toggle by using:

`app:passwordToggleDrawable` - Drawable to use as the password input visibility toggle icon.
`app:passwordToggleTint` - Icon to use for the password input visibility toggle.
`app:passwordToggleTintMode` - Blending mode used to apply the background tint.

More details in [TextInputLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html).

[image]

Comment: By default i want password not be visible. How do i achieve this

Comment: How to achieve the same functionality with support library 23.4.0

Comment: How to remove the background horizontal line?

Comment: app:endIconMode="password_toggle"

Comment: @ShivaAcharjee You can do this by set this to xml or programatically
android:inputType="text|textPassword"

Comment: does anyone knows how to set checked or not the password toggle?

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want any extra bool or dependencies, then

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_input_pass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/MyEditText" />
```

and

```
password_toggle_imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (et_input_pass.getTransformationMethod().getClass().getSimpleName() .equals("PasswordTransformationMethod")) {
            et_input_pass.setTransformationMethod(new SingleLineTransformationMethod());
        }
        else {
            et_input_pass.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
        }

        et_input_pass.setSelection(et_input_pass.getText().length());
    }
});
```

that's it!

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. Easy and quick

Comment: Yes this should be and accepted answer. One of the worst things in android development is dependencies.  It causes major build issues.   This answer worked on two different phone first shot! Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Please try this code.

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.ivPasswordToggle:

                switch ( motionEvent.getAction() ) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"show",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         etPassword.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                         etPassword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"hide",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I hope it will work, thanks.

Comment: thanks.the code works fine ,but everytime i click on drawable the edit text cursor goes to first position

Comment: try this in both switch cases.....  etPassword.setSelection(etPassword.getText().length()); & let me know, if it does not work.

Comment: i got the answer, i had to to add edittext.setSelection(Position). inside both, action down and action up.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following method. Here, we are setting a compound drawable which when clicked will show or hide the password:

```
private boolean passwordShown = false;

private void addPasswordViewToggle() {
        getPasswordEditText().setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2; //index

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (event.getRawX() >= (getPasswordEditText().getRight() - getPasswordEditText().getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                        if (passwordShown) {
                            passwordShown = false;
                            // 129 is obtained by bitwise ORing InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
                            getPasswordEditText().setInputType(129);

                            // Need to call following as the font is changed to mono-space by default for password fields
                            getPasswordEditText().setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
                            getPasswordEditText().setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.locked_icon, 0); // This is lock icon
                        } else {
                            passwordShown = true;
                            getPasswordEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

                            getPasswordEditText().setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.unlocked_icon, 0); // Unlock icon
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 fragmentLoginBinding.imageViewEye.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (!isPasswordVisible) {
            fragmentLoginBinding.editTextPassword.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            fragmentLoginBinding.imageViewEye.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.feather_eye_crossed));
            isPasswordVisible = true;
        } else {
            fragmentLoginBinding.editTextPassword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            fragmentLoginBinding.imageViewEye.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.feather_eye));
            isPasswordVisible = false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

**app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the accepted answer that was posted few years ago? Please consider upvoting the existing answer than pasting same answer again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little addition to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163578/11209741) for those, who wondering who to implement custom drawable for toggle

1. In your resources:

drawable/password_toggle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/eye"
        app:tint="@color/black_600_8a"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/eye_closed"
        app:tint="@color/black_600_8a" />
</selector>
```

`state_checked` is the state when password is visible

**Note:** use `app:tint` in the drawable and not `android:endIconTint` in the layout to change the colour of your toggle, as the latter won't work properly with selector

2. In your layout xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/password_toggle">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            ...
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Hope this will help someone as much as it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an EditText or AppCompatEditText you can implement that desired output by;

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spinner_role"
                >

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_password"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:autofillHints="@string/password"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:backgroundTint="#59A6B6"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button_password_toggle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility_off"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/register_user_password_et" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In your .kt file;

```
if (registerUserBinding.editTextPassword.transformationMethod.equals(
            PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
        )
    ) {
        registerUserBinding.registerUserPasswordEt.transformationMethod =
            HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance()
        registerUserBinding.buttonPasswordToggle.setImageDrawable(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                registerUserBinding.registerUserPasswordEt.context,
                R.drawable.ic_visibility
            )
        )

    } else {
        registerUserBinding.editTextPassword.transformationMethod =
            PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
        registerUserBinding.buttonPasswordToggle.setImageDrawable(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                registerUserBinding.registerUserPasswordEt.context,
                R.drawable.ic_visibility_off
            )
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Implement the TextInput like below. The main attribute that gives that feature is app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/resetpasswordactivity_textinputlayout_newpassword"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                android:theme="@style/loginActivityHintStyle"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/resetpasswordactivity_textinputlayout_newconfirmpassword"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/resetpasswordactivity_textinputlayout_resetcode"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.15">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/resetpasswordactivity_textinputedittext_newpassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:labelFor="@id/resetpasswordactivity_textinputedittext_newpassword"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/black_inputtext_color"
                    />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose a solution inspired by [@shanezzar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54088623/361413) that does not require changes to existing legacy `android:inputType="textPassword"` EditText layouts (e.g. adding a show-password icon/checkbox). It simply shows the password when the EditText has input focus and hides it when the EditText loses focus (`password` is an EditText):

```java
password.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
   if (hasFocus) {
      password.setTransformationMethod(new SingleLineTransformationMethod());
   } else {
      password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
   }
   // move cursor to end of text
   password.setSelection(password.getText().length());
});
```