# Android Studio doesn't change color in PasswordToggleDrawable

Tags: java, android, xml

This is the code in the layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/selector_password_icon">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/activity_login_password_text_value"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>


</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And this is the code in the Selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_eye_active"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_eye_inactive" />
```

The Icons have different colors (Gray and Black) but the same shape and size. The problem is that both icons show the same color, therefore stays the same if its active or inactive.

Edit: I want to use XML because it will be used in multiple pages

Comment: As an alternative, you may use `passwordToggleTint ` in order to give the drawable a different color instead of switching two drawables. Found that one [here](https://medium.com/@moyinoluwa/password-visibility-toggle-android-support-library-revision-24-2-0-98b422087e5a) and [here](https://medium.com/creinno-studio/password-visibility-toggle-android-1571aeeffc05)

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38735102/edit-text-password-toggle-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your color values, use color values directly, follow this link:
 https://www.codevscolor.com/android-material-design-tutorial-10-password-visibility-toggle/