# why password text is getting like this in edit text in layout when I add android:inputType="textPassword"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to add password and confirm password in my register page . But when I am trying to use input type attribute for password and confirm password edit text instead of text I am getting dots  .

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="329dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="356dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:text="PASSWORD"
    android:textColor="@color/White" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="329dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="293dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:text="CONFIRM PASSWORD"
    android:textColor="@color/White" />
```

Comment: isn't that how password input is supposed to work?

Comment: That's how it should work but after entering the password it should hide the password . And before that it should show "password". But initially I am getting dots instead of text "password"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want placeholder text, you should set it like this:

`android:hint="PASSWORD"`

instead of this:

`android:text="PASSWORD"`

Color of the hint text can be set like this:

`android:textColorHint="white"`

Comment: you're welcome. You might want to accept an answer if it helped you solve your issue .  Happy coding!

Comment: Can You tell  How to enable Toggle in my code above for password field ?

Comment: If you have another question, it's best to post a new one instead of asking more in the comments. That being said, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163578/16050098) will probably help you. Also, often a question is already solved elsewhere, so try to search for an existing answer first.

Answer (score 0):

`android:text` attribute will set the text of the associated `EditText`, this will be equivelant of the input typed by the user. If you want to guide the user that this field is for password, you should use the `android:hint` attribute. For example if you declare `android:hint="Password"` the user will see the text Password inside the `EditText` and when clicked, the text will disappear.

Comment: Thank u so much foe helping me out !!! I appreciate it !!!