# Why InputType password is shown?

Tags: android, input, passwords, maskededitextender

My code :

```
final EditText input = new EditText(VideoRunActivity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        input.setLayoutParams(lp);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

It shows the input which is typed by me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to hide password?

Comment: i want to hide input characters...........

Comment: Can you show us your xml?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext

Comment: You should show us more of your code. This isn't enough for us to help you.

Comment: it was programmatically. not have xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out

```
input.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Comment: You better explain your solution instead of simply posting some code. Maybe it's worth reading [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try do this:

```
input.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

So code be like that:

```
    final EditText input = new EditText(VideoRunActivity.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            input.setLayoutParams(lp);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
input.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `XML`:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: i want it programmatically.

Comment: Did you try this input.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());