# How to hide EditText (asterisk) programmatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I was ordered to separate a password EditText into separate EditTexts. This is working fine, except when I change focus from one EditText to another, the previous EditText does not change to an asterisk (*). How do I make it?

JAVA:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    TextView text = (TextView) getCurrentFocus();

    if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
        View next = text.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
        if (next != null) {
            next.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
                android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

It doesn't work because it requires you to type another digit in the same EditText in order for the digit to be masked. I have one EditText per digit so this never happens.

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: @Abhi I added it to my question

Answer (score 0):

I guess,U missed this element in your Edittext

> android:inputType="textPassword"

Programatically as,

> mEdit.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());

refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext)

Comment: I already have 
                    android:inputType="numberPassword"
It doesn't work because it requires you to type another digit in the same box in order for the digit to be masked. I have one box per digit so this never happens.