# How to set android:inputType using databinding

Tags: android, data-binding

I am trying to toggle between the old way of displaying a password with the following databinding expression:

```
android:password="@{isMyFlagTrue}"
```

However when I try to use the `inputType` in lieu of the now deprecated password attribute, I can't seem to successfully set the password type. I have tried:

```
android:inputType="@{isMyFlagTrue? InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD : InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD)}"
```

But this made no effect on the inputType of the `EditText` view. Even when I try to set it directly to the invisible variety it is still visible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could just add a TextWatcher to your EditText and handle the input yourself. Much easier, and customizable.

Comment: Yes but NJ a texWatcher just takes an `Editable s` value. However the input type depends on something outside the scope of the inputString

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was only suggesting that you can use TextWatcher to interpret the input before it is displayed in the input field, and replace with asterisk mark, while one can store the value in a local variable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set input type use data-binding like

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType='@{condition ? (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD) : InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT }'
    />
```

after importing `InputType` like

```
<data>
    ...
    <import type="android.text.InputType" />
</data>
```

Comment: @Phan_Van_Linh is that an inclusive OR that is represented by `|`? What does that do?

Comment: This is the way we set inputType programmaticalyl: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext. Then when using databinding, we should do like it

Comment: <import type="android.text.InputType"/> to import InputType class

Comment: Use something like `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL` for number input